How to add all the jar from a project folder using pom.xml?
I want to add all the jar from lib folder of the java project.In gradle it is done by the following code:
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')

How to achieve the same result using maven?

You should read through this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Does this answer your question? Adding all the files in a folder to build path dependencies using Maven

@M.Rizzo i can not use this bacause its group and artifact id i dont know and a number of dependency is attached inside it.

@JakariaMasud if you don't know the group and artifact id then make them up of your own. Since you won't be interacting with a maven repo anyway there is probably not much harm in doing this. Otherwise there might be maven repositories that are able to search artifacts by checksum. You could calculate checksums of your jars and look them up (if you believe them to be publicly available jars).

Actually you don't need to make anything up. mvn install:install-file only requires one parameter (the path to the file)

@g00se i want the process of loading all the jar automated.I don't want to install with the file path bacause my project has a lot of jar.so it needs to run a lot of maven install comand.

So, something like find lib -type f -name \*.jar -exec mvn install:install-file -Dfile='{}'  \;

In case of maven you can try by adding the required dependencies from the website named maven repositories.
In this site search your required dependency and choose the version which is used by most of the users , copy and paste that xml dependency code in your pom.xml then press ctrl + s by saving it will automatically add all the required jar file into your dependency folder
click here to redirect maven repo

I have to load dependencies from local directory rather than maven repository because client has this requirement.

check out this answer this may be useful to you link
